# Finding his own path

Tags: soft-question, career-development

I am a graduate student in major mathematics and now the time has come to choose a "specialization" (I have to choose 3 between 4 subjects).

I like algebra a lot and I am also interested in biomathematics. However I can't choose between these two directions. I like the way algebra is built, but I don't know what research looks like in this field. On the other hand, I do have a good idea of biomathematics research looks like.

I know that it is a very subjective question and that I should discuss of that with my teachers, but I would like to have your impressions and advices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look at Bernd Sturmfels' book *Algebraic Statistics for Computational Biology*.  He applies algebraic geometry to a variety of statistical problems arising in biology.

Comment: [This one ?](http://yaroslavvb.com/papers/pachter-algebraic.pdf)

Comment: Yes. ${{{{{{{{}}}}}}}}$

Comment: What could be the name of such a specialization ? Algebraic statistics ? I have never heard of that

Comment: You've heard of it if you've heard of that book.  But maybe it never saw the light of day before the book appeared.

Comment: Indeed, I have never heard of both... I like the way group theory and markov chains mix

Comment: Certainly there are now a field of algebraic statistics, see: http://jalgstat.com/               http://www.jasonmorton.com/morton/aspsu2012/index.html